# Регулярные выражения в nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

При гуглении регулярных выражений мне попадаются только огромные статьи и толстые книги. А мне надо только понять как работает это:

```
 location ~* ^.+\.\w+$ {
     root /home/box/web/public;
 }
```

Окей. Начал читать книгу, закончил три главы уже, а полного понимая того, что написано выше все еще нет и, судя по всему, если идти таким путем, то не скоро будет.

Не могли бы вы просто в двух словах объяснить символику этого примера.

Comment: синтаксис регулярных выражений бывает весьма разным (например, в разных спецификациях, наиболее распространённые из которых: bre, ere, pcre). начальную информацию можно почерпнуть даже из [википедийной статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`^` - означает, что соответствие будет искаться с начала строки, а не с любого символа. Выражение `/box/` будет соответствовать и box-web и home-box-web, а `/^box/` только первой строке.

`$` - означает привязку к концу строки `/index\.php/` будет соответствовать и site.ru/index.php и site.ru/index.php?v=3, выражение `/index\.php$/` будет соответствовать только первому варианту.

`.+` - любое количество символов. Точка - любой символ, комбинация `.+` - один или больше любых символов.

`\.` - Так как точка специальный символ, то для того, чтобы обозначить точку, ее нужно экранировать слешем.

`\w` - любой символ, который может составить слово `\w+` - любое количество таких символов (один или больше).

Т.е. выражение `^.+\.\w+$` охватывает почти любой URL. Прицел изначально был на выражения вида hello/index.php.

Регулярные выражения - специальный декларативный язык. Выучить его не так просто, как может показаться на первый взгляд. Его декларативная природа не позволяет использовать опыт и знания, приобретенные скажем в императивных языках программирования. Поэтому изучая его следует запастись терпением - это может занять время. Квантификаторы и спец.символы придется выучить наизусть и добиться полного понимания их работы, как операторов ветвления и циклов в императивных языках. В замен вы получаете очень компактный инструмент для манипуляции строк.